# Why doesn't `FOO=42 echo "$FOO"` print 42 in Bash?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, echo

I'm confused by this behaviour:

```
$ FOO=42 echo "$FOO"

$ FOO=42 && echo "$FOO"
42
```

I'm accustomed to using `VARNAME=value cmd` to specify environment variables for other commands, so I was surprised to discover it doesn't work when `cmd` is `echo`. This might have something to do with `echo` being a Bash built-in. Is this the case? If so, is using `&&` the best way to specify environment variables for Bash built-ins?

**Update:** `&&` is no good, as it results in the environment variables being set permanently, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Technically, `FOO=42` only sets a shell variable. It is not exported to the current environment unless you mark `foo` to be exported with `export FOO`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter that `echo` is a built-in. The reason is that variables on the command line are evaluated before executing the command, they're not evaluated by the command. You could get the result you want with:

```
FOO=42 bash -c 'echo "$FOO"'
```

This starts a new shell to execute `echo $foo`. Since the argument to `bash` is in single quotes, the variable is not replaced by the original shell.

Comment: Terrific answer. I never knew about the `bash` command. `bash -c` seems very powerful.

Answer (score 3):

The replacement happens *before* the command is executed:

1. `$FOO` is replaced with its current value.
2. `echo ""` is executed with `$FOO` set to 42.

Try:

```
FOO=42 sh -c 'echo "$FOO"'
```

Comment: Seperating the 2 with a semi-colon works also:
FOO=42; echo $FOO

Effectively makes them 2 commands so FOO gets set before the echo command is evaluated.

Comment: And then you have a stray variable.